# Unidentified question in my profile

Tags: support, questions, reputation

Today, suddenly my reputation dropped by 20. I couldn't find out what happened, and then when I looked into the reputation graph, there was an unidentified question I hadn't asked. Is my account hacked or something? Or is this a bug?

This is the graph

[image]

And this is my questions list, I haven't asked any question as such

[image]

Comment: You mean a post was *deleted* and you lost 20 points for that? We cannot see such posts in your profile. Do you have a link for that post?

Comment: Tick the "show removed posts" option on the reputation tab in your profile and do you have any information about this "unidentified question".

Comment: I did tick "show removed posts". It showed a question asked today. But I'm certain I didn't ask it.

Comment: You let Robin wander around your computer again, right?

Comment: I just want to know if it's a bug or someone else hacked my account. Is there a way to know that?

Comment: If the question was deleted today, it will show in today's rep, not when it was asked.

Comment: That certainly is a valid answer given that I actually had asked the question

Comment: @darknight: I was able to find the post because it was still listed on Google and I could find it by its title. Next time, please include a *link* to that post, even if you cannot yourself see it us 10k+ users (as well as moderators) *can*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **answered** that question in August last year: [What should I do to my personal website on Google Search to be the first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429197/what-should-i-do-to-my-personal-website-on-google-search-to-be-the-first) (10k+ only).

The question was deleted today by community vote, and your answer was deleted along with it. You got one upvote, one downvote and one accept for that post, so you had gained +25 - 2 == +23 points for it, which you now lost again.

The question was very much off-topic and would have been auto-deleted if you had not answered it; try not to answer questions that are this far outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: no, the answer was unaccepted on delete.

Comment: That is so cool.. Thanks.. I thought my account was hacked

Comment: @Martijn, I should have thought of that. Otherwise the question wouldn't have been deletable.